# sed print between two line patterns only if both patterns are found

Tags: bash, sed

Suppose I have a file with:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Start Line 3
Line 4 
Line 5
Line 6
End  Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Start Line 10
Line 11
End Line 12
Line 13
Start line 14
Line 15
```

I want to use `sed` to print between the patterns only if both `/Start/` and `/End/` are found.

`sed -n '/Start/,/End/p'` works as expected if you know both markers are there and in the order expected, but it just prints from `Start` to the end of the file if `End` is either out of order or not present. (i.e., prints line 14 and line 15 in the example)

I have tried:

```
sed -n '/Start/,/End/{H;}; /End/{x; p;}' file
```

Prints:

```
# blank line here...
Start Line 3
Line 4 
Line 5
Line 6
End  Line 7
End  Line 7
Start Line 10
Line 11
End Line 12
```

which is close but two issues:

1. Unwanted leading blank line
2. End  Line 7 printed twice

I am hoping for a result similar to

```
$ awk '/Start/{x=1} x{buf=buf$0"\n"} /End/{print buf; buf=""; x=0}' file
Start Line 3
Line 4 
Line 5
Line 6
End  Line 7

Start Line 10
Line 11
End Line 12
```

(blank lines between the blocks not necessary...)

Comment: Is another "start line" allowed inside a block? (for example, if line 5 is a start line, do you want the block 3-7 or the block 5-7?)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Great question. No, It does not need to handle overlapping or nested `/Start/` blocks. Just handle (by not printing) the lack of a `/End/`

Comment: So the answer is block 5-7?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: No. With the example input, it should print lines 3-7 and lines 10-12. Two line blocks.

Comment: Just curious - since this can be done trivially, robustly, and portably in awk and you already know how to do it in awk, why are you looking for a sed solution?

Comment: @EdMorton: Fair question. I thought I could do it trivially, robustly, and portably in sed too, but it does appears that awk is easier for this example. Sed has capture groups and a more complete example involved that (i.e., a replacement in the print block.) Perl is better still, but I am still focused on sharpening my Unix utilities skills. Thanks

Comment: GNU awk has capture groups but they're just a convenience and you can get the necessary behavior with a POSIX awk, it just might take you writing slightly more code. After 30+ years of using sed and 20+ of using awk my recommendation is you use sed for simple substitutions on single lines and use awk for everything else. Even if the awk code for the simple stuff ends up slightly less brief, at least you're learning how to use awk for when you need to deal with the complex stuff! I would be interested in seeing the more complete example you mention in a new question if you care to post it.

Comment: @EdMorton: I agree with you. I mainly thought I might be missing something really simple with `sed`. It is idiomatic to print a block `sed -n '/Start/,/End/p'` but until I had a use case it did not really occur to me that there is no test for the second mark and the idiomatic `awk` method is more easily modified to handle it. Again -- I thought there might be something really easy in `sed`. It kinda is, but on OS X it gets a little strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU sed: after encountering `Start`, keep appending lines as long as we don't see `End`; once we do, print the pattern space and start over:

```
$ sed -n '/Start/{:a;N;/End/!ba;p}' infile
Start Line 3
Line 4 
Line 5
Line 6
End  Line 7
Start Line 10
Line 11
End Line 12
```

Getting the newline between blocks is tricky. This would add one after each block, but results in an extra blank at the end:

```
$ sed -n '/Start/{:a;N;/End/!ba;s/$/\n/p}' infile
Start Line 3
Line 4 
Line 5
Line 6
End  Line 7

Start Line 10
Line 11
End Line 12
[blank]
```

Comment: On OS X I get `unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`

Comment: @dawg Hmm, try adding a `;` after the `p`, or actually enter newlines instead of semicolons, does that work?

Comment: OSX sed is nasty for this. There used to be some trick to make this work but I forgot

Comment: On OSX this `sed` command will work: **`sed -n -e '/Start/{:a;' -e 'N;/End/!ba;' -e 'p;}' file`**

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed and sed from Solaris 11:

```
sed -n '/Start/{h;b;};H;/End/{g;p;}' file
```

Output:

```
Start Line 3
Line 4 
Line 5
Line 6
End  Line 7
Start Line 10
Line 11
End Line 12
```

If `Start` is found **copy** current pattern space to hold space (`h`) and branch to end of script (`b`). For every other line **append** current pattern space to hold space (`H`). If `End` is found copy hold space back to pattern space (`g`) and then print pattern space (`p`).

Comment: This works on OS X IF I put a `CR` after the `b` branch to the end. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this works with OS X: `sed -n -e '/Start/{h;b' -e '};H;/End/{g;p;}' file`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'x{buf=buf ORS $0} /Start/{x=1; buf=$0} /End/{print buf; buf=""; x=0}' file

Start Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
End  Line 7
Start Line 10
Line 11
End Line 12
```

Here is a `sed` version to do the same on OSX (BSD) `sed` ([Based on Benjamin's sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35659338/548225)):

```
sed -n -e '/Start/{:a;' -e 'N;/End/!ba;' -e 'p;}' file
```

Comment: I know that I can use `awk` or `Perl`. I am trying to replicate with `sed` specifically.

Comment: How annoying that we have to break up the command on OS X. Functionally, is `sed -e 'something' -e 'more'` producing `sed -e 'something\nmore`?

Comment: It is indeed annoying. Where we have labels in sed, it needs to be in a separate `-e` part

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer your awk solution, but:

```
  sed -n -e '/start/,/end/H' -e '/end/{s/.*//; x; p}' input
```